# Tensorflow: Nice way to make updates to internal variables?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm new to Tensorflow, so forgive me if I'm asking an obvious question.

I have an "function" with internal state, which I call "pd_encode".  It implements `y[t]=kp*x[t]+kd*(x[t]-x[t-1])`, where `y[t]=pd_encode(x[t])`.  I defined it as follows:

```
def pd_encode(x, kp, kd):
    x_last = tf.Variable(initial_value=np.zeros(x.shape), dtype=x.dtype)
    x_enc = kp*x + kd*(x-x_last)
    with tf.control_dependencies([x_enc]):
        update_op = tf.assign(x_last, x)
    return x_enc, update_op
```

Now, this works as expected, but it's a bit annoying to have to pass the update op all the way up to where I call `run`.  It forces external functions to pass around the internal state variables of `pd_encode`, which seems *not right*.  I found I can make the update implicit by changing the definition to:

```
def pd_encode(x, kp, kd):
    x_last = tf.Variable(initial_value=np.zeros(x.shape), dtype=x.dtype)
    x_enc = kp*x + kd*(x-x_last)
    with tf.control_dependencies([x_enc]):
        update_op = tf.assign(x_last, x)
    with tf.control_dependencies([update_op]):
        x_enc = tf.identity(x_enc)
    return x_enc
```

Now, this does what I want, but using the identity function here seems like a horrible hack.  Does tensorflow not have a nicer way to achieve this?

Comment: here `x_enc` op is computed before `update_op`, since in first context you are defining `update_op` with `x_enc`. why are you again putting reverse dependency here? when you compute the `update_op` `x_inc` will be automatically computed.

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to compute `update_op` WITHOUT having to return it from the function and pass it into my `session.run` command.  I want to do this because it makes the code cleaner.